# Expat prints out garbage when I print to screen or file

Tags: c++, xml, expat-parser

When I print out information from my XML document I get �� before each line.
Here is my XML document.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Here is my code

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <expat.h>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
void XMLCALL start(void*,const char*, const char**);
void XMLCALL end(void*,const char*);
void XMLCALL character(void*, const char*, int);
int main()
{
    int size;
    fstream fin("note.xml", ios::in | ios::binary | ios::ate);
    size = fin.tellg();
    char* data = new char [size + 1];
    fin.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    XML_Parser parser = XML_ParserCreate("ISO-8859-1");
    XML_SetElementHandler(parser, start, end);
    XML_SetCharacterDataHandler(parser, character);
    fin.read(data, size);
    XML_Parse(parser, data, size , fin.eof());
    XML_ParserFree(parser);
    fin.close();
    delete [] data;
}

void XMLCALL start(void* data, const char* name, const char** atts)
{
   if((strcmp(name, "note")) == 0)
   {
       printf("-- Note --<br> ");
   }
   else if((strcmp(name,"to")) == 0)
   {
       printf("To:  ");
   }
   else if((strcmp(name,"from")) == 0)
   {
       printf("From: ");
   }
   else if((strcmp(name,"heading")) == 0)
   {
       printf("Heading: ");
   }
   else if((strcmp(name, "body")) == 0)
   {
       printf("Message: ");
   }
}

void XMLCALL end(void* data,const char* name)
{
    printf("<br>");
}

void XMLCALL character(void* data, const char* info, int length)
{
    printf("%s",info);
}
```

This is what it prints out:

```
-- Note --<br> 
�To:  Tove<br>
xFrom: Jani<br>
xHeading: Reminder<br>
xMessage: Don't forget me this weekend!<br>
x<br>
```

This is what I want it to print out:

```
-- Note --<br> 
To:  Tove<br>
From: Jani<br>
Heading: Reminder<br>
Message: Don't forget me this weekend!<br>
<br>
```

Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.
Thank You

Comment: The newlines? I.e. the `"\r\n"`?

Comment: Possible a Unicode BOM header. By the way you should better use strncmp to compair strings. Many critical erros are produces with this command.

Comment: @rekire: Wait, what? That doesn't make sense to me. It's like "don't use mmap, it's dangerous and evil!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Character is called for the '\n' on the end of the line with length = 1.  The other characters are junk after the '\n' in the info string.

Comment: So character has to  be called for each element?

Comment: I used a string, getline(), and a while loop to parse each element.